# How to import a Portlet EAR into the workspace

Tags: websphere, portlet, ear, websphere-portal

I have an portal EAR folder that I downloaded from the portal server directly. Its expanded and not one .ear file. Is there a way I can load it into my workspace, do some changes and launch on my local portal server?

May sound simple but I am getting crazy
Sorry..

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here

[Importing an enterprise application EAR file](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/tjimpear.html)